# How to select a cell from a table in selenium using java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to select a cell from a table in selenium when I have unique class name for the table

Below is the dom of the table

```
<table class="unique-class-name">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>data1</td>
      <td>data2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>data4</td>
    </tr>`your text`
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried below code but it is not able to find the table cell

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.className("unique-class-name"));
for(int i=0; i<expectedTableBodyData.size(); i++){
            for(int j=0; j<expectedTableBodyData.get(i).size(); j++){
                WebElement tableBodyCell = table.findElement(By.xpath(".//tbody/tr[i+1]/td[j+1]"));
```

I am not able to find the `tableBodyCell` element, I have to use the loop because of some 2D array input data.
I also tried `./tbody/tr[i+1]/td[j+1]` and `child::tbody/tr[i+1]/td[j+1]` and `descendant::tbody/tr[i+1]/td[j+1]` but it did not work

Comment: Post the URL and the complete code you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
table.findElement(By.xpath(String.format("((.//tbody/tr)[%d]/td)[%d]", i+1, j+1)));
```

The brackets within the xpath to clearly identify which element is being indexed are important.